# Trouble installing NumPy and Matplotlib on Mac (snow leopard)

Tags: python, macos, numpy, matplotlib, osx-snow-leopard

Having installed Python 2.7 from the python website I have since tried to install both NumPy and Matplotlib, but when I do so a box comes up telling me it requires system python 2.6. Do I need to be running an older version!?

Comment: I run SL and python 2.7. Installing numpy via [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) worked without problems.

Comment: EPDFree[http://www.enthought.com/products/epd_free.php] is an easy to install alternative.  You get python2.7, numpy, scipy, etc.  It is free so long as you don't try to resell it.

Comment: You need a fairly new version of gcc (4.5 IIRC) for numpy. You didn't mention *how* exactly you are trying to install numpy so I don't know if this applies ...

Comment: @Carpertsmoker - I'm installing it from the sourcefourge link which is like a prepackaged installation file I just double click it then it throws up an installation/setup thing which goes through three of five steps before telling me that it cannot install on the selected drive because it doesn't have python 2.6

Answer (score 5):

Sourceforge version trees of those modules are tricky for OS X users. :P I was having problems installing them because I did't realize there were dmgs exactly built for Snow Leopard...

There are different version of .egg and .dmg files, you should pay attention to download. If have SL, you should installi these versions of [NumPy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.6.1/numpy-1.6.1-py2.7-python.org-macosx10.6.dmg/download) and [SciPy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.9.0/scipy-0.9.0-py2.7-python.org-macosx10.6.dmg/download). I'm running SL on a 32bit machine which has Python2.6 Python2.7 and Python3.2 installed and running fine.

I don't want to say that you're blind nor I'm accusing you, but it might happen that you miss the right binary version. :P