# How do you use numpy in google app engine (Python)

Tags: google-app-engine, numpy

numpy is supported as a library in google app engine according to the official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27). I was not able to import it after a few trials, can anyone share the code to use it?

I believe it should be called in app.yaml with:

```
libraries:
- name: numpy
  version: "1.6.1"
```

And then be imported in the script somehow. I tried the obvious:

```
import numpy
```

but it gave me the following error:

ImportError: No module named numpy

Any simple code is appreciated, for example how do you do the ["numpy.average"](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.average.html) function in a google app engine script?

```
>>> data = range(1,5)
>>> data
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> np.average(data)
2.5
```

Comment: can you expand on "but it didn't work:"? Was there an error?

Comment: just updated the question, I got the following error "ImportError: No module named numpy"

Comment: Is this happening in your dev server or in production? And you can see how shell-27.appspot.com can import successfully numpy. It's yaml is here http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/shell/app.yaml.shell-27

Comment: With the SDK, you need to install numpy yourself (download from http://scipy.org/Download#head-0dfc04e10313d2e70988c6cb3bef7a9e09860c8f or use pip)

Comment: Thanks guys, that solves it - I was having the problem in dev server, in which I had wrongly assumed that the numpy package would be installed with the app engine SDK.

A quick tip for mac OS X users, numpy packages require a bit of attention when downloading, check out this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904435/trouble-installing-numpy-and-matplotlib-on-mac-snow-leopard

Answer (score 12):

If you want it to work locally you have to download and install it locally (I got mine from here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)

Besides that you have to make sure you are running python27, and that you're importing it in the app.yaml file, e.g.:

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: no

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.py

libraries:
- name: numpy
  version: "1.6.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the code for the Predator app demoed in the [Getting the Most Out of Python 2.7 on App Engine](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/gooio2012/300/) by Brian Quinlan. He walks you through it starting at 11:00