# Google App Engine doesn't find numpy

Tags: python, google-app-engine, numpy

I'm trying to use numpy module on the Google App Engine, but it keeps appearing like below..

```
import numpy
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

I already downloaded numpy module as you can see.

```
In [1]: help(numpy)
Help on package numpy:

NAME
    numpy

FILE
    c:\users\wlsk5_000\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py

DESCRIPTION
    NumPy
    =====

    Provides
      1. An array object of arbitrary homogeneous items
      2. Fast mathematical operations over arrays
      3. Linear Algebra, Fourier Transforms, Random Number Generation
```

How can I handle this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you use numpy in google app engine (Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418558/how-do-you-use-numpy-in-google-app-engine-python)

Answer (score 2):

Numpy is included in the App Engine SDK already, so you don't need to download it, but you *do* need to enable it. You do that by adding it to the `libraries` setting in app.yaml, as described in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Configuring_libraries).